# Conway's Game of Life Applying Rules of Life Issues Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create Conway's Game of Life for android for a programming class I am taking. I am able to get an initial pattern drawn on the board no problem. I am running into issues when I want to create the next generation.

Here is my method to create the next generation.

```
public void createNextGen(){
    int neighbors;
    int[][] nextGen = new int[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

    for(int h = 0; h < HEIGHT; h++){
        for(int w = 0; w < WIDTH; w++){
            neighbors = calcNeighbors(h, w);
                if(currentLife[h][w] == 1){
                    if(neighbors < 2){
                        nextGen[h][w] = 0;
                    } else if (neighbors > 3){
                        nextGen[h][w] = 0;
                    } else {
                        nextGen[h][w] = 1;
                    }
                } else if (currentLife[h][w] == 0){
                    if(neighbors == 3){
                        nextGen[h][w] = 1;
                    } else {
                        nextGen[h][w] = 0;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    copyGrid(nextGen, currentLife);
}
```

Here is my method to calculate neighbors.

```
private int calcNeighbors(int x, int y){
    int total = 0;

    for (int h = -1; h <= +1; h++) {
        for (int w = -1; w <= +1; w++) {
            if (currentLife[(HEIGHT + (y + h)) % HEIGHT][(WIDTH + (x + w)) % WIDTH] != 0) {
                total++;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

This is the initial pattern that starts on the grid.

```
public void initGrid() {
    resetGrid(currentLife);

    currentLife[8][(WIDTH / 2) - 1] = 1;
    currentLife[8][(WIDTH / 2) + 1] = 1;
    currentLife[9][(WIDTH / 2) - 1] = 1;
    currentLife[9][(WIDTH / 2) + 1] = 1;
    currentLife[10][(WIDTH / 2) - 1] = 1;
    currentLife[10][(WIDTH / 2)] = 1;
    currentLife[10][(WIDTH / 2) + 1] = 1;

}
```

I don't think the issue lies in my onDraw method, as this initial pattern shows up as expected. Its the following generations that are jumping all over the place, and I figure I must have done something wrong in the createNextGeneration method.

I am using the integer 1 to represent an ALIVE cell, and the integer 0 to represent a DEAD cell.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple mistake in order of parameters - you are sending `y`,`x` to the `calcNeighbors` method which expects `x`,`y`.

```
calcNeighbors(h, w);
...

private int calcNeighbors(int x, int y)
...
```

I suggest you change the method to:

```
private int calcNeighbors(int y, int x)
```

Since you are using h, w (y, x) order in rest of the code.

Comment: Oh my...haha thank you so much. I knew it was something stupid!! So if I change the calcNeighbors method to (int y, int x) that should solve it??